# Is there a way in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet to figure out which method is called at runtime

Tags: java, servlets

We are using a tool Based upon java and internally it uses javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet to implement HTTP Methods(GET,POST etc). we are trying to figure out in which method we are. At design time we know which method it is but at runtime do we have any parameter/ field which maintains method name used eg. doGet() or do Post()

Answer (score 1):

`request.getMethod()` is the method that you can use to check whether its a post or a get

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get an object "HttpServletRequest", this object has getMethod() which returns the HTTP verb (get, post,...)